# Converting List of objects into pages in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get page with a number of items in each page. For some reason, this method returns the complete list instead of page of 5 items.

```
public Page<Item> searchPagedCategoryByName(@RequestParam String name) 
{
    Category category;
    category = categoryRepository.findCategoryByCategoryName(name);
    List<Item> items = category.getItems();

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0,5);
    Page<Item> page = new PageImpl<Item>(items, pageable, items.size());
    return page;
}
```

Comment: Because you need to make your **repository** do the paging! You're basically grabbing the _whole lot_ from the underlying database and dumping it into a `List` then trying to page after - that's too late. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/.

Comment: Extend you repository from PagingAndSortingRepository, then use 
`Page<Item> items = repository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 5));`

Comment: Also the declaring on one line then assigning on the next is a really weird pattern - I'd stop doing that if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

Create the repository extending **PagingAndSortingRepository** which provides perform pagination and sorting capability and then you can use like this,

Here is a code snippet from my practice workspace.

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository< Category, Long> {
  List<Category> findCategoryByCategoryName(String categoryName, Pageable pageable);
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner pagingAndSortingRepositoryDemo(CategoryRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {
        log.info("Category found with Paging Request PageRequest.of(page [zeroBased Page index], Size)");
        repository. findCategoryByCategoryName(name , PageRequest.of(0, 5)).forEach(category -> log.info(" :=> " + category));
    };
}
```